# How to get user_id in facebook when has logged facebook but not authorized?

Tags: facebook

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
            // app, and response.authResponse supplies
            // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
            // request, and the time the access token 
            // and signed request each expire
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            alert(uid);
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
            // but has not authenticated your app
            // logged in and connected user, someone you know
            var uid = response.id;
            alert(uid);
        } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            alert("the user isn't logged in to Facebook.");
        }
    });
```

How to get uid when not_authorized ?

Answer (score 2):

> How to get uid when not_authorized ?

Not at all. Facebook does not give you such information, unless the user has authorized your app.

It’s a matter of privacy – think about it, every site on the net could set up their own app, and would get your FB user ID once you browse it. Would *you* want f.e. a random p0rn site that you might get redirected to from somewhere else without you even wanting this to happen to get your Facebook user ID? Of course you would not.